# Apple Watch Watchkit 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I am using Xcode 7.0 beta version and have done all the necessary updates, but for some reason I am continuing to get an error regarding my "WKInterfacePicker" object. Even when just attaching an outlet from the picker to the code, I get the error "Use of undeclared type 'WKInterfacePicker' ". I figured that it may be lack of installing the new documentation, but I double checked that I did have the docs in Xcode. (By the way I am building for the Watchkit 2.0).

Comment: You'll need to make the question more informative. Based on the error you've shared, I can only assume that the code using WKInterfacePicker lacks ```import WatchKit``` -- please share more of the code.

Answer (score 2):

On the WKInterfaceController, try removing all targets except the WatchKit Extension target.